# How to add a constant character to the end of a HTML search form

Tags: html, forms, search, wildcard, asterisk

I have a search form which I have to let my visitors use wildcard for their queries. The script that I am using allows wildcard searches by adding `?` and `*` in a way which is quite similar to Windows search. Although, at the moment it works properly, nobody would add an asterisk at the end of its query in his first attempt.

So, I wonder if it is possible to somehow edit my HTML form so as to automatically let them search by wildcard. For example, when they search for "New York", I want my page to show results for "New Yorker" as well. The query "new york*" would perfectly work for my search form, but as I have explained I should sort it instead of users and let them use this feature by default.

```
<form action="index.php" method="get" style="margin:0" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input class="input" name="q" type="text" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="-1" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="strict" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="srch" />
<input type="submit" class="submitok" value="Search!" />
</td>
</form>
```

Comment: just append an asterisk to the search query before submission...

Comment: Thanks but still do not know where to do that. I have tried "value" tag but absolutely did not work.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: This is the code

<form  action="index.php" method="get" style="margin:0" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input class="input" name="q" type="text" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="-1" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="strict" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="srch" />
<input type="submit" class="submitok" value="Search!" /></td> </form>

@sodawillow I use a script which is written on PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply attach an event listener to the submit click, and before submitting the form add an asterisk to the end of search query...

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("submitok")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
   document.getElementsByClassName("input")[0].value+="*";
});
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="get" style="margin:0" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input class="input" name="q" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="-1" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="strict" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="srch" />
    <input type="submit" class="submitok" class="submitok" value="Search!" />
</form>
```

once the click listener code executes, the form will get submitted with the asterisk suffix

Comment: there is nothing wrong with using javascript, provided his clients wont disable it in the browser, and there is nothing wrong with seeint the asterisk, since they can add it on their own as well. moreover, op can check if an asterisk was inputted, and if not then append one.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will allow you to add the missing * at the end of the search string, but we need your PHP code to help here.

Example :

```
if(isset($_GET["q"]) && $_GET["q"] != "")
{
  $query = $_GET["q"] . "*";
}
```

Comment: Php side of the script is too complicated for my level. I have used Banana's javascript. Thank you very much for your help!